# ggplot. Adding regression lines by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

If I plot this

```
dodge <- position_dodge(.35)   
ggplot(mediat, aes(x=t, y=Value, colour=factor(act),group=id )) + 
geom_point(position=dodge) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Value-sdt, ymax=Value+sdt), 
width=0, position=dodge) +  theme_bw() + geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE,
fullrange=TRUE)
```

I get this
[image]

As you can see the regression line is not plotted.
with +stat_smooth(method=lm, fullrange=TRUE, se = FALSE) the result is the same.

I've found that removing the "group=id" I can get the regression lines but

then

```
ggplot(mediat, aes(x=t, y=Value, colour=factor(act) ))+ geom_point(position=dodge) +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Value-sdt, ymax=Value+sdt), width=0, position=dodge) +
theme_bw() + geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)
```

[image]

As you can see, now it plot the lines but I loose the dodge function by groups.

How can I get both things at once?. I mean, regression lines by "id" on the first uncluttered plot?

Any other solution with base plot, lattice or any other common package would also be welcome.

Regards

Comment: maybe put the group = id in the aes for the geom_smooth

Comment: I've also tried that but it doesn't work either

Comment: Sorry, put the group = id in the geom_point so the geom_smooth cannot see it. Might help to see some data

Comment: OK, it works as
ggplot(mediat, aes(x=t, y=Value, colour=factor(act)))+geom_point(position=dodge, aes(group=id)) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Value-sdt, ymax=Value+sdt, group=id), width=0, position=dodge)+theme_bw()+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE)

But the lines don't cover the whole range, I'd like it to intersect the margins.

Comment: `geom_smooth` does not like to extrapolate. I would be tempted to calculate the model coefficients and give them to `geom_abline`